# Dropdown Select in Rails Form with Registered User Names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown select in a Rails form and I want to fill the dropdown menu with all of the user names of the registered users. Any ideas for how to go about doing this?

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class = "form-group col-md-3">
    <%= f.label :room_number %><br>
    <%= f.select(:user_name, class: "dropdown-toggle") %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go with:

```
<%= f.select :user_name, User.pluck(:name) %>
```

## EDIT

to allow multiple selection, you would want to go with following:

```
 <%= f.select :user_name, User.pluck(:name), { multiple: true, size: 2 } %> #or any number
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there are a way to choose multiple users?

Comment: I mean like a nested select. This rails cast is the closest thing I found to what I want, but it's old and I can't seem it get it to work. http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1?view=asciicast